# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) error occurs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my env file is :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=a2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

My database.php file has :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'a2'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

and it initially had password passwd@321 and now i have changed both .env and database.php file but its showing

[image]

I tried cache clear

`php artisan cache:clear`

but it shows :

[image]

Comment: DB name also showing `madison`

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Unless your host limits you to having a single database user, each application should have it's own MySQL user and that user should have just the permissions required for it to run, and only have permission to access it's own database only (maybe even locked down to table level). That way if one application's MySQL user gets compromised, the other MySQL users for the other applications don't get compromised as well

Comment: @arun it shows same error as i showed when i tried cache clear

Comment: @SpacePhoenix i am in localhost for now  .....

Comment: Have you tried `DB_HOST=localhost`?

Comment: also check the name of database because its not same in error stack and your config settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove the double quote from `DB_PASSWORD`

```
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

To

```
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Update your `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=a2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

after run `php artisan config:cache` command in your terminal/cmd

Comment: Please restart your server and check

Comment: @pravinpoudel: are you sure password is blank?

Comment: yes password is blank but in error page there is password that i had earlier shown

Comment: OR please rename cache folder to cache2  from bootstrap/cache and generate new empty cache folder in bootstrap and try to run `php artisan cache:clear` command in terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171444/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-pravin-poudel).